# Eigenstates of coupled Angular Momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

SO I have a hamiltonian:
$$H=\alpha J_1\cdot J_2$$
And I am asked to find the eigenstates and eigenvalues of this Hamiltonian in terms of products of the eigenstates of the z components of the individual spins.

The wording of this question is kind of confusing me.  I could solve it by rewriting it in terms of $(J_1+J_2)^2,J_1^2,J_2^2$ and then find the eigenvalues, but that is not in terms of the z components.  How should I go about doing this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is essentially just asking you to perform Clebsch-Gordan (CG) decomposition, namely a change of basis on the Hilbert space $\mathcal H_{j_1}\otimes\mathcal H_{j_2}$ of the composite system of spins.

Recall that for each of the Hilbert spaces $\mathcal H_{j_1}$ and $\mathcal H_{j_1}$ there exist orthonormal bases of eigenvectors of $\mathbf J_1^2, J_1^z$ and $\mathbf J_2^2, J_2^z$ respectively, and these bases are 
\begin{align}
  \text{for $\mathcal H_{j_1}$}&:\qquad  \{|j_1, m_1\rangle\,|\,m_1=-j_1,-j_1+1,\dots,j_1-1, j_1\} \\
\text{for $\mathcal H_{j_2}$}&:\qquad  \{|j_2, m_2\rangle\,|\,m_2=-j_2,-j_2+1,\dots,j_2-1, j_2\}
\end{align}
It follows that an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for the composite Hilbert space $\mathcal H_{j_1}\otimes\mathcal H_{j_2}$ consists of the set of all tensor products of these basis elements;
\begin{align}
  \text{for $\mathcal H_{j_1}\otimes\mathcal H_{j_2}$}:\qquad  \{|j_1, m_1\rangle|j_2,m_2\rangle\,|\,-j_1\leq m_1\leq j_1, -j_2\leq m_2\leq j_2\}  \tag{$\star$}
\end{align}
This is what being referred to as

> "...products of eigenstates of the z components of individual spins."

So once you've found the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, which you will presumably write in terms of the basis
\begin{align}
  \{|j,m,j_1,j_2\rangle\},
\end{align}
 you just need to decompose them into the tensor product basis in $(\star)$ above.

Comment: So how could I do this generally, given J.  I do not know what spin they have.  The coupled would go from $j_1+j_2,...,|j_1-j_2|$.

Comment: @yankeefan11 To do this for a given $j_1$ and $j_2$, you either look in a CG table, or you compute the CG coefficients yourself.

Comment: Yeah, but I am not given $j_1,j_2$

Comment: @yankeefan11 As far as I am aware, no closed form expression for CG coefficients for general $j_1$ and $j_2$ exists, hence the need for a table.

Comment: Thats why I am confused on how to answer this question.  I could solve it given $J_1,J_2$, but I'm not given that

Comment: @yankeefan11 Well then it's time to complain to the prof. it seems like.

Comment: Yes it is.  Im guessing it will be a spin 1/2, but I will get that answered.  Thanks for your help (again)!

Comment: Also, as a followup, when I am given $J_1\cdot J_2$, is that the same as $J_1 \otimes J_2$?

Comment: @yankeefan11 Nope, and I have *just* the right thing for you to read http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60409/how-to-tackle-dot-product-for-spin-matrices/60414#60414 (the answer written by your's truly :)).

Comment: Awesome.  I will have a read through it

Comment: And it is in fact spin 1/2, so I am in luck!

Comment: @yankeefan11 Haha...trivial!