# Do spin wavefunctions live on a Hilbert space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, electrons, quantum-spin

This question comes to mind while reading the quote in different books which is  "Hilbert space is infinite dimensional". While the electron spin is 2 Dimensional problem. Secondly, we assume that spin wave function is square integrable which is a property of a function in Hilbert space. THen how do we know if spin wavefunctions belongs to Hilbert Space or not? Please help me clear this concept of Hilbert space.

Comment: Honestly, I find the usage of "Hilbert space" in physics needlessly confusing. It's frequently used as a synonym for "the state space of the system under consideration," when all it means is a particular kind of vector space. It makes no more sense to say that something "lives in Hilbert space" (which we see all the time) than to say it "lives in vector space." For the same reason, "Hilbert space is infinite dimensional" makes as little sense as "vector space is infinite dimensional."

Answer (score 6):

A [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) is a complex vector space with an inner product that is complete w.r.t. the norm induced by that inner product. It may be finite-dimensional, it may be infinite-dimensional - the dimensionality is not part of the definition. Neither is square-integrability. Either your sources are wrong - or you are misinterpreting them, not paying attention to a difference between the generic definition of *a* Hilbert space and the definition of a *specific* Hilbert space as the space of states of a physical system.

The space of states of position (or momentum) wavefunctions of objects without spin in quantum mechanics is the infinite-dimensional Hilbert [space of square-integrable functions $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space).

The space of (spin) states for a particle with spin $s$ is the finite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^{2s+1}$.

Since spaces of states are [combined](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/54899/50583) via the tensor product, the space of states of position (or momentum) wavefunctions for  an object with spin $s$ is the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\otimes \mathbb{C}^{2s+1}$, which is the space of $\mathbb{C}^{2s+1}$-valued functions that are square-integrable in each component.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent clarification. I was reading Griffiths on this topic and through his whole discussion he assumed wavefunctions as a function of position, probably for reader's convenience. Later I found in Zettili the exact definition of Hilbert Space. Your comment helped me a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: For what it's worth, "wave function" (almost?) always refers to the Hilbert space of position / momentum (which, as you know, occupy the same space), and confusingly sometimes only to the position representation _of_ that space. Nobody calls a spin state a "wave function" (though again, confusingly, sometimes the position $\otimes$ spin state is called that).

Answer (score 1):

A [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) is a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) $\mathcal H$ with an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) which satisfies a particular metric condition with respect to the sense of distance induced by this inner product. (Specifically, the space must be [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space), i.e., every Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal H$ converges to a limit in $\mathcal H$.)

Every finite-dimensional inner-product space is complete (because it is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^n$ and $\mathbb C^n$ is complete), so therefore every finite-dimensional inner-product space is a Hilbert space.

As such, anybody who claims that "Hilbert space [must be] infinite dimensional" is basically dead wrong about that. Hilbert spaces *can* be infinite-dimensional, but they don't need to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the idea.

Comment: "anybody who claims that "Hilbert space [must be] infinite dimensional" is basically dead wrong" - this statement may be too strong, as this depends on the definition. Sometimes Hilbert space is defined as an infinite-dimensional one (https://www.britannica.com/science/Hilbert-space)

Comment: Emilio, you answer is excellent as usual, but completeness is  not a topological condition, as, roughy speaking, it is not invariant under homeomorphisms.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Many thanks! This one got away from me, and I still find it surprising. [Indeed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565350/), completeness is not topological. Who knew! (apart from, you know, everybody...).

Comment: $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $(-1,1)$ are homeomorphic but the former is complete whereas the latter is not, using the natural metric topology. (Ah yes you quoted a link on that fact).