# What is the dimension of two quantum systems with bases $\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$, combined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

Quantum system A has a basis $\{a_1, a_2\}$. System B has a basis $\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$. A and B evolve according to their own Hamiltonian and do not interact at all. If I consider A and B as one large system, is the dimension of the vector space 5 or 6?

Comment: How many different combined states $a_m b_n$ can you write down?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54896/50583

Answer (score 2):

The Hilbert space is the tensor product of the two, i.e. $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$, and its dimension is the product of the two dimensions: $\mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{H}) = \mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{H}_A) \mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{H}_B)$. In your case $\mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{H}) = 2 \cdot 3 = 6$.
In simple words, when $A$ is in state $a_1$, $B$ can be in one of the three states $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ and the same happens when $A$ is in state $a_2$.
By the way this happens also when the two subsystems are interacting.

Answer (score 2):

As per usual in quantum mechanics lets say that A is described by states in a space $\mathcal{E}_A$ and B by  $\mathcal{E}_B$. These systems are fully determined by the basis $\{a_1, a_2\}$ and $\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$.

If the quantum systems do not interact, then the space containing the states of the full system A+B is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{E}_A \otimes \mathcal{E}_B
\end{equation}
whose basis vectors can be written always as
\begin{equation}
|a_n b_m \rangle := |a_n\rangle \otimes |b_m\rangle.
\end{equation}

So the real question is: how many different combinations of $a_n$ and $b_m$ can you make? If $a_1 \neq a_2$ and $b_1 \neq b_2 \neq b_3$, which **they **must** be**, the answer is 6.