# Angular momentum addition in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, observables

If we consider the addition of orbital sngular momentum **L** and spin angular momentum **S** to produce the total angular momentum vector **J**, then **J** is a member of the vector space that is constructed by taking the tensor product of the vector spaces associated with **L** and **S**. Why don't we take direct sum of the vector spaces of **L** and **S** instead to construct the **J**-space? Why are we particularly using tensor product to combine the spaces?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54896/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Related : [Total spin of two spin- 1/2  particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156).