# Why do we use the Tensor Product of Hilbert Spaces?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, tensor-calculus

What is the reason that we use the *tensor product* of two Hilbert Spaces in order to describe a two-particle system in quantum mechanics?

So what is the precise reason to use the *tensor product* and **not** for example a *direct sum* of Hilbert spaces in order to describe a two-particle system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should it be obvious that independent quantum states are composed by taking the tensor product?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54896/)

Comment: Related : [Total spin of two spin- 1/2  particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342123/total-spin-of-two-spin-1-2-particles/342156#342156).